# Rails and mandrill in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mandrill

Is it possible to send mails via mandrill without configure any :smtp setting by just using the mandrill API key.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, take a look at https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.ruby.html however if you signed up for a Mandrill account on or after December 1st, 2015, you must add SPF and DKIM records and verify ownership of your sending domains before you can send email through your account